# Footer on all page except last one

Tags: richtextbox, document, rtf, richtext

Hi how can I prepare rtf file that will display footer on each page except the last one. I've find only this option

```
\footer     Footer on all pages
\footerf    Footer for the first page only
\footerl    Footer on left pages only
\footerr    Footer on right pages only
```

Thanks for any answers.

Answer (score 1):

Footers are reset by section breaks, so you can define your footer using `\footer` on the first page and then use `\sect\sectd` on the last page to clear it, and it will appear on all pages except the last.